# Android getting Activity instance in Application from Handler

Tags: android, android-activity, handler, progressdialog

I am using Handler for communicating between Current Activity and a subclass of Application.
Subclass is having a thread which processes web service calls.
Subclass may also have a ProgressDialog instance.

I want to show ProgressDialog when http call is starting and dismiss dialog when call is finished.

For this to happen, I need to access Activity from Handler. And then assign activity to Dialog using setOwnerActivity.

Is this possible? I tried and cant not get activity from Handler. The max Handler can give is Thread which sent message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The application class is unaware of what activity is running.

The only thing that can be done is to let application class know about activity is by a setter method which is not recommended as it may lead to memory problems.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried sending the Instance of the Activity using a `Message` with parameter `msg.obj`?

Btw, I think you should be using a [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) instead of riddling it with complicated code.

Comment: Passing activty to msg.obj may lead to memory leak so avoiding it. and having one dedicated thread only to serve http calls seems to be better approach.Ofcource handlers comes with more maintainance.