# getting Application instance from a handler in android

Tags: android, multithreading

I am trying to solve the following problem:
I am writing an application that has multiple activities that share data model.
The data is fetched from DB when application starts and saved as global variables in Application class extension as follow:

```
class MyApp extends Application {

  private MyData myData;

  public MyData getData(){
    return myData;
  }
  public void setData(MyData d){
    myData = d;
    sendBroadcast(new Intent("DATA_UPDATED"););
  }
}
```

The AndroidManifest.xml is updated of course and everything works great - every activity can read the data and update it, other activities can get notifications of data change using the BroadcasrReceiver.
Things get problematic when I have another thread that should update the main (GUI) thread:
I have a service that contains a callback when new data is received from the db. the callback is running on new thread, so updating my Apllication data model must being done on the main thread.
for that I used handler as follow:

```
public void ServiceCallback(...newData) {           
    //Pass the message up to our handler to make the update on the main thread.
    Message receipt = Message.obtain(mHandler, 0, newData);
    receipt.sendToTarget();       
}

    //Handle incoming message from remote on the main thread (GUI thread)
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler() 
{
     @Override
     public void handleMessage(Message msg) 
     {
    //read new data from the message - from msg.obj field, no prob.             
    //but - how can i get to my application model instance????
     }
};
```

So i though passing it exactly as I passed the new_data in the message, but I saw [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481928/android-getting-activity-instance-in-application-from-handler)

that it may lead to memory leak...? I didnt understand if its true and why, and maybe I have another solution that anyone can suggest? I would really appreciate it. Is it possible to use broadcast receivers between threads? maybe this is my solution?

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit unclear what exactly you are trying to do. A few things to note: using an application object for shared/global data doesn't really buy you anything. You can simply use a singleton. If you want to use the `Application`, you can add a static `getInstance()` method to it, since there is only one instance it is by definition a singleton, adding the method will simply make it easier to access from non-activity classes. You don't have to update data in the `Application` class on the main thread. You only need to do things on the main thread when you are dealing with the UI.

Additionally, if you simply want to send a message to another thread, a `Handler` is sufficient. There is no need to involve `BroadcastReceivers`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually my first implementation was simple singleton, but I had a bug when my app was in background for some time, the singleton was removed so I got null reference. This is why I turned to the Application class.

Comment: If your process is killed, data in a singleton will naturally be lost. But the same goes for the Application class. It is in no way special besides having an `onCreate()` method where you can initialize stuff. You can achieve the same thing with a singleton with lazily initialized data.

Comment: My process is not killed - the service is still running, but cant read the data from the singleton. The singleton's memory was cleared from some reason which I cant understand and I though maybe if I use the Application class it would work. This issue is killing me :(

Comment: There is no other reason to clear the memory from a singleton. You service will be restarted (in a new process), but Android doesn't know about your singleton and has no way of re-initializing it. That is why  it was 'empty'.

Comment: So the problem should occur only when I bring the app to front?

Comment: It's not as simple as that. Any time another app comes to the foreground, your app (now in the background) is eligible to be killed, if the system needs more memory. If there is enough memory, it will stay alive. If you start 4-5 different apps one after another, chances are you app will be killed and restarted when you go back to it.